# Repeat external command for each line in awk

Tags: awk

With the following content in the clipboard:

```
curl "foo" --compressed ;
curl "bar" --compressed ;
curl "baz" --compressed ;
```

The following command creates one line for each clipboard-line:

```
pbpaste | awk '{"pwgen 10 1" | getline pass; print substr($0, 1, length($0) -1) ">>myfile-" pass ".jpg"}'
```

generating the output below:

```
curl "foo" --compressed >>myfile-du7EeHegh7.jpg
curl "bar" --compressed >>myfile-du7EeHegh7.jpg
curl "baz" --compressed >>myfile-du7EeHegh7.jpg
```

**Question:**

The issue here is that `pwgen 10 1` seems to be executed only once at the beginning, while I'd like it to be executed for every new clipboard line, hence generating a new unique filename for each line. How to make sure that this call to `pwgen` is repeated and not only executed once at the beginning?

**Desired output:**

```
# each filename is unique
curl "foo" --compressed >>myfile-zus83j10ai.jpg
curl "bar" --compressed >>myfile-nbjfo2pa9d.jpg
curl "baz" --compressed >>myfile-ahqdugpo90.jpg
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when using external command in awk and using [`getline from a Pipe`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Getline_002fPipe.html#Getline_002fPipe), better to assign the command into a variable like `my_command="my external command here"` and call it with `my_command |getline to_save` that later you should [`close(my_command)`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Close-Files-And-Pipes.html) it in order to make output distinct for every run;
it's also suggested to do a `close(my_command)` in `BEGIN{...}` block to ensure no command is open for the `my_command`.

additionally do testing on the getline return code and proceed if it only was succeed; so you will have to do:

```
pbpaste |awk 'BEGIN{ close(cmd); }
{ cmd="pwgen 10 1";
  if (cmd | getline pass) {
      print substr($0, 1, length($0) -1) ">>myfile-" pass ".jpg";
      close(cmd);
  } else { print "running command failed!"; exit 1; }
}'
```

However with above if the command itself failed, getline still will be return success return-code since we don't check command success/failure, to put test on command status we can do:

```
pbpaste |awk 'BEGIN{ close(cmd); }
{ cmd="pwgen 10 1 || echo failed";
  if ((cmd | getline pass)>0 && pass!="failed") {
      print substr($0, 1, length($0) -1) ">>myfile-" pass ".jpg";
      close(cmd);
  } else { print "running command failed!"; exit 1; }
}'
```

quote from manual:

> If the same file name or the **same shell command** is used with `getline`
> more than once during the execution of an awk program ([see section
> Explicit Input with getline](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Getline.html#Getline)), the file is opened (or **the command is
> executed**) the first time only. At that time, the first record of input
> is read from that file or command. The next time the same file or
> command is used with getline, another record is read from it, and so
> on.

from the above link [Explicit Input with getline](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Getline.html#Getline) mentioned:

> The getline command returns 1 if it finds a record and 0 if it
> encounters the end of the file. If there is some error in getting a
> record, such as a file that cannot be opened, then getline returns -1.
> In this case, gawk sets the variable ERRNO to a string describing the
> error that occurred.

see also:

- [Points to Remember About `getline`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Getline-Notes.html#Getline-Notes)

Comment: You should also test that the call to `getline` succeeded before using the value of the variable that you hope it populated (`pass`), see http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline.

Comment: @EdMorton yes, updated answer to mention that. thanks

Comment: `getline` returns 0 on eof, <0 on error, >0 on success. `close()` returns with the exit status of the command.